# Explosion animation

Tags: android, surfaceview

I want to do an explosion animation with three different bitmaps representing different stages of the explosion I already have the bitmaps loaded, I tried using a for loop but the images get by too fast to see. I have this all in my surfaceview class, is there a way to properly carry out this function this sort of explosion image switching, or any pointers without the images flashing by so fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're interested in Drawable animation.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html

Answer (score 0):

Drawable animation works, but you could also have a runnable that changes the bitmap, sleeps for some time, and then changes the bitmap again.

Its hacky, but depending on your situation, might be more convenient.

Comment: Thats what I was aiming for at first, but the sleeps didnt work in between image calls.

Comment: Have any idea of what might have interrupted the sleeps?

Comment: When i try putting sleeps in between each bitmap call, that results in a pause then the explosion images just go away as if they were being shown in background

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write

`new ParticleSystem(this, numParticles, drawableResourceId, timeToLive)
.setSpeedRange(0.2f, 0.5f)
.oneShot(emitterview, numberOfParticles);`

also add this dependency

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.plattysoft.leonids:LeonidsLib:1.3.1'
}`

For more detail, Please refer this library.
https://github.com/plattysoft/Leonids